# Why use CFTimeInterval instead of just double?

Tags: objective-c, double

What is the reason of using `CFTimeInterval` instead of double in Objective C?

Comment: semantics and maintainability in case the underlying data type changes

Comment: Here's a better question - why would you ever use something like double to represent time?

Answer (score 2):

The actual type used might change from one platform to another, as `int` did when CPUs transitioned from 32 to 64bits. Also, variables defined with the platform independent type could be considered more self descriptive - nobody will wonder if a CFTimeInterval variable is in hours, milliseconds, etc, because the type is documented to mean seconds.